# Home server does not boot any more after system upgrade

Tags: 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I have a little home server running on Ubuntu. Although I'm a Windows user in real life (shame on me), I have some basic Linux knowledge, so I managed to set up this machine using a [great (German) tutorial](https://www.techgrube.de/tutorials/tutorials-linux/uebersicht-ubuntu-20-04-homeserver-nas-teil-1). I'm using the server as a NAS (to provide my lossless music to Sonos via Samba and for backup purposes) and to host Home Assistant in a VM. The system has now been running stable for about 1.5 years, and I was pretty happy with it.

When I logged into the server via RDP yesterday, Ubuntu told me that there's a system upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS (I was on 20.04), so I clicked the "Upgrade" button after checking that everything is up to date via `sudo apt update`, but nothing happened - the dialog just disappeared. Googling revealed that I also can do this on the terminal, so I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Everything appeared to be working fine if I remember correctly, at least up to the point where services were restarted, so I lost the RDP connection (should have done this via SSH in the first place, I guess). I then logged into the system via SSH and ran `sudo reboot`. However, the system did not come back.

I connected the system to a monitor and keyboard (since I could not access it via SSH) and rebooted, only to find out that I was ending up in "emergency mode". After hassling around a bit (I do not remember exactly what I did), the system appeared to get farer: UI started (but showed the "Unrecoverable error - contact admin" screen and the unhappy smiley), but at that point I was able to connect via SSH (and also noted that my Home Assistant instance was running). I then ran `sudo apt update` which worked besides one problem:

```
appstreamcli: symbol lookup error: appstreamcli: undefined symbol: AS_SYSTEM_COLLECTION_METADATA_PATHS
```

977 packages were ready to be updated. However, running `sudo apt upgrade` failed with the error message

```
E: Der dpkg-Prozess wurde unterbrochen; Sie müssen manuell »sudo dpkg --configure -a« ausführen, um das Problem zu beheben.
```

(sorry for the mixture of German and English error messages - that's how Ubuntu povides them to me). Thus, I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but execution got canceled because of too many errors. Running `sudo apt update`  again, I was down to 975 packages :-), but `sudo apt upgrade` failed and suggested to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, which I did. This appeared to be fixing the problem, so after another `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt autoremove`, I was down to "All packages are up-to-date".

I then rebooted, but the system got stuck at the "emergency mode" again :-(

Since the server was able to launch SSH service as well as my VM at some point in time, I figured that it might not be completely broken, so I decided to ask here before going for a complete reinstall. In case you have read this far, please give me some advice on what to try, or let me know which info you need (and how to get it :-) ) - any help is greatly appreciated!

One more thing: "Emergency mode" suggests to run `journalctl -xb` - I did that, but don't see anything in red despite a missing device referring to a HDD I removed some time ago (I never bothered to remove the according configuration because it just slowed down booting because of 90s waiting period, but didn't seem to cause any other problems). Since I do not know how to access this file without SSH, I'm not able to provide it - I have taken a picture of the final "boot information" (including the info printed by `uname -a`):

[image]

Edit: Updated offered version (see comments below for whole story :-) )

Comment: Thanks already! To be honest, I wasn't completely sure on which version I was, so I checked https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and figured I was on 20.04, and was offered `*.*.1` (I'm sure about the .1, and there does not seem to be a 22.04.1 yet according to the link above)!? Now that I think about it, that page is probably outdated - Ubuntu would have offered me 20.04.5 instead of .1 (for the sake of staying on 20). But I'm sure that I haven't upgraded the release version in the meantime - I only worked with `apt update` and `apt upgrade` the whole time. I'll try `apt full-upgrade` right now..

Comment: For the record: `apt full-upgrade` suggests to call `apt autoremove` for two packages, but didn't update anything.

Comment: Sorry the wiki was a little *outdated*; if you check again you'll see 20.04.5 (*what was the fully-upgraded 20.04 system*) and 22.04.1 (*later 22.04 release*) has been added.  Normal upgrades of a 20.04 system would have upgraded you to 20.04; but there is no special warning for that as you're upgrading from 20.04 to 20.04; ie. just having more security fixes applied. The .1/.2/.3/.4/.5 means little to most things; only if using HWE kernel or doing installs & thus no upgrade notices is provided.  Release-upgrades (ie. 20.04(.x) to 22.04(.x) however is different and requires permission

Comment: Thanks for fixing the release page! I'm a developer and know about semantic versioning, so that's what I had guessed... Since I'm on an LTS version, and since I had never been offered any upgrade before (I log in via RDP every once in a while), I had assumed that I had been offered a service release for 20 - should have payed more attention, I guess. Back to the original question  is there a way to go back to 20.4.whatever? If there isn't: how can I debug the issue (which I expect to be a relatively minor one as pointed out in my question)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The key info (which was missing) was that when I continued booting by pressing `Ctrl-D`, I would get the following error message:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency target has 'start' job queued but 'stop' is included in transaction.
```

Googling that error message led to [this solution](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/currently-supported-releases/kubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo/software-support-aa/657810-failed-to-start-default-target), where a superfluous reference to USB was contained in `/etc/fstab`. Since that file contained a reference to my missing HDD (that I had mentioned in the question), I commented it out - and now the system is booting again!

Not sure why this entry didn't cause any problems for 1.5 years, and now does, but who cares :-)